# Compiling just one class in netbeans in a web app

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-applications, netbeans, compiler-construction, compilation

I was wondering if there is a way to compile just the file I have changed in a web application project rather than building the whole project again. It takes a lot of time to build the project all over again rather than just compiling that one file. I am able to use the "run test" feature to  check if the class has been written properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check out the JRebel plugin for NetBeans.  JRebel is a hot deployer that works with web servers.

http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/installing-jrebel-for-netbeans/

http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/